# How to properly splice entries out of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas csv, assuming my dataframe is mydataframe.

My data is registration data where I have a csv for:

```
Name, RegistrationID, DateSignedUp, Course
```

I want to 'clean' the data up in my data frame by removing any row of any 'Name' who had less than 5 registrations.

I am able to get the count of registrations per name using the following:

```
mydataframe.groupby('Name')['RegistrationID'].count()
```

How do I create a new dataframe with all rows where 'Name' has more than 5 registrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `transform`

```
n=5
mydataframe=mydataframe[mydataframe.groupby('Name')['RegistrationID'].transform('count')>n].copy()
```